# Water leaking from garage slab hole patching after foundation repair

Tags: water, slab, leaking

I had my foundation repaired last year. They dug couple of holes in my garage slab then patched it with concrete. After that I started to see water coming out from patching area during/after the rain. Apparently the water is coming between the old and new concrete edge of the patch. I called the foundation company, they came and removed old patch, put a plastic under the hole and poured concrete again. But this doesn't help. Is there a better way to make the patching water proof ? [image]

Comment: It's my opinion that there is no "patch" that would make this watertight.  Water will find it's way through.  The problem is that there is TOO MUCH WATER PRESSURE on the underside of the slab and the "repairs" were substandard.

Comment: how far below wetted grade is this garage slab?

Answer (score 0):

Sealing concrete repairs is extremely challenging the crack line from the new to the old concrete is usually where it will leak.

The only way I have been able to stop these kind of leaks is with hydraulic cement. Hydraulic cement is kind of expensive but when I have to cut out toilet drains or plumbing in a slab I will fill it with hydraulic cement.

It doesn’t always work but it has rarely failed me.

it sets up fast that is a large area but if it is leaking on the old / new that would be my recommendation. Usually my cuts are only 4” wide so I am not sure if it will work on a several foot wide space.

Added to provide additional possibilities.

I have tried to make a step and I usually do drill a dozen or more holes and put 16 penny galvanized nails in the holes to hold the patch like rebar. There have been a couple of times when the ground water was just two much so I dug a trench behind the house in this case on the low side then used a piece of 3/4 pvc pipe connected to water to drill a hole horizontally just beyond the leak point once I was able to slide the pipe in without water I drilled a bunch of holes 1/16” the length of the pipe and filled the trench with rock. It worked for 3 years but we sold the home after that so I am not sure how long my makeshift foundation drain into the dry well lasted.

Freeman suggestion of trying to use hydraulic on the border or a moat bridging the 2 layers may help but if I was taking that much out I would use all hydraulic cement, but even that is not guaranteed as I found out a few times over the years.

The only absolutely sure way is to move the water before it can build enough pressure to leak through.

Comment: Would it be recommended or feasible to dig out a trench or moat 1-2" wide around the edge of the patch, encompassing some new and old concrete and fill just the trench with the hydraulic cement?